# having problems with the xml layout, multiple relative layouts are being created

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have an array string that is added to an abc.xml and textview id label

```
this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.abc,R.id.label, days));
```

In my abc.xml file I have a relative layout to show the nav bar, just once.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#4C4646"
    >
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout02" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#3E3D3D"
    android:paddingRight="3dp"
    android:paddingLeft="3dp"
    >
     <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/back_listing"
        android:background="@drawable/android_back_button"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp">
      </Button>

<TextView android:id="@+id/search_label" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp" 
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/back_listing" 
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/search_submit"
    android:textSize="20px"
            android:text="Nav Bar"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
    />


<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/search_submit"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/android_forward_button"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"

    >
</Button>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and then

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10px"
android:textSize="15px" 
android:id="@+id/label"
>
```

which fills the textview with the array list

But the problem i have is the nav bar shows at the top followed by the first item in my array list then the nav bar follows again, then the second item from my array list then the nav bar, this happens till the end of array list. Also as if, the navbar is in a loop with my arraylist. Now when i take off the content of the relative layout( navbar) leaving the textview, it shows perfectly but ofcourse i want the nav bar there showing once, ontop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to seperate this:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10px"
android:textSize="15px" 
android:id="@+id/label"
>
```

into a different xml file perhaps call it row.xml Then use that file with your adapter. If you want the nav bar at the top then put it there with alignParentTop=true in your main layout, and put the ListView below it by setting `android:layout_below="@+id/navBarLayout"`